# Drawing behavior when a fragment is written to multiple times in a single pass

Tags: opengl, rendering

This seems really basic, but I'm confused and can't find a clear answer anywhere.

What happens to a target fragment of a rendertarget if the fragment is written to multiple times within one pass (e.g. by drawing two identical triangles above each other), assuming depth and stencil testing is disabled?

Does this just use the behavior specified with the current blend state? If not, can I modify this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does indeed use the blend state to determine what happens (along with the depth and stencil states).

The result will be exactly the same as if you'd drawn the two triangles in separate draw calls.

Comment: Thanks. Any chance of providing a source for it (e.g. quote OpenGL specification)? It would be nice if there was no room for ambiguity for future users reading the answer, if they for example find conflicting statements via google or something.

Comment: I'm not at all familiar with the spec, I just know what happens from experience. A quick search found http://www.cs.rit.edu/usr/local/pub/wrc/courses/cg1/doc/opengl/redbook/AppE.pdf but it doesn't appear to explicitly state the full ordering of things.